# Core data crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS for one entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Hopefully someone can help me debug this problem as EXC_BAD_ACCESS is the only error I receive. Also it happens only for one Entity.

I have multiple entities in my core data model (created using xcode 7.2). Now I create a new version of core data model and add new entity (using xcode 7.3).
Now each time i try to access this newly added entity, core data crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. As I am guessing some how this new entity release before i try to access?

The strange part is this crash only happens in iOS 8. Its working fine for iOS 9

Comment: Please show the error and which line it occurs on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found the issue, its due to wrong data type. When I save, some data types eg: Boolean not saved correctly. Somehow it works fine on ioS 9